# CMake - Linking external C++ library

Tags: c++, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have an external .cpp library that requires both the following libraries: `atlas`, `llpack` and `lblas`

Now if for example, I compile using terminal (on the same machine) I can use the following:

`g++ main.cpp hmm.cpp -I /usr/include/atlas -L /usr/lib64/atlas/ -llapack -lblas`

This will work. I don't know how to include these libraries into the CMake list in ROS. I have, currently, the following:

```
rosbuild_add_executable(build1 src/hmm.c)
```

What would I have to add into my CMake list to make this work?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126951/cmake---linking-external-c++-library/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
link_directories( /usr/lib64/atlas )
```

equivalent to -L /usr/lib64/atlas of gcc/g++

And after :

```
rosbuild_add_executable(build1 src/hmm.c)
```

you put

```
target_link_libraries( build1 lapack blas )
```

equivalent to -llapack -lblas

Note: First arg of target_link_libraries is the previously defined target to link.

Note: no prepended -l in target_link_libraries, i e. if your external lib is named libmy_lib.so you just add my_lib to target_link_libraries

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4